# Using logitech mouse and keyboard with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

Hi I've just installed Virtualbox and I've installed Windows 7

I have a Logitech K270 Keyboard and T620 Mouse, and the host system is Ubuntu 13.04.

The Keyboard and Mouse lock each time I try and launch the guest. They completely stop responding. I can't regain control and I can't use them in the guest machine.

I've looked at the virtualbox forums (they aren't completely clear so I may have missed something)

[Virtualbox forums with additional links](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8758)

The things I have tried unsuccessfully are:

```
1. Turn off auto-capture
2. Turn off (and on) absolute pointing device
3. Turn off (and on) EHCI USB 2.0 controller
4. Enable and disable USB Controller
5. Change Network Adapter to NAT,Bridged and Host-only
```

I dont really want to switch to VMPlayer until I've had a good go at making this work.

Would anyone have any thoughts

Comment: Are you using the Guest Additions?

Comment: yes @peanut_butter I am. thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the guest additions?